# Top Visitors Report displaying IP addresses

Tags: claims-based-auth, web-analytics

We have a SharePoint 2010 CBA site where anonymous access is disabled. Recently the Top Visitors reports started displaying IP addresses. Could this be related to client vpn's? I havent been able to find much on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing this issue right now too, does anyone have an idea why this report shows IP addresses of computers instead of names? As far as I know, they could not be authorized. Situation is even weirder, because the most active IP belongs to user, who basically hates the portal and does not use any (offline) synchronization or datasheet, works with documents only. Report looks like this:

[image]